# How to loop through a list of cell values and apply one value to each sheet in an excel worksheet file

Tags: excel, vba

Say I had a list of cell values whose length corresponded to exactly to the number of sheets in my excel file

How would I loop through the list to change the G1 value of each sheet in order?

I.E if the list of values was 1,2,3 then sheet one would have g1 = 1, sheet 2 would have g1 = 2 etc.

Here is what I have tried so far

Gives Run-time Error 91:
Object Variable or With block variable not set

```
Sub Test1()
      Dim x As Integer
      Dim myCellSetValue As Range
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      Range("A2").Select
      For x = 1 To NumRows
         Set myCellRangeSetValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("G1")
          myCellSetValue.Value = ActiveCell.Value
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
   End Sub
```

Comment: My previous question was actually different, I thought it would reopen post editing based on the popup on the screen but it didn't hence my repost. Looking for more of a general direction as I can't find how to loop based on an existing list.

Comment: Oh - didn't see that you had edited your previous question... but yeah this is still a bit too broad. Surely you can put together at least a loop through each worksheet, or a loop through cell values?

Comment: To start: Suggest you research how to loop cells on a worksheet then learn how to loop worksheets. Write some code to *attempt* to accomplish what you want and when you get an error post your code and describe the error.

Comment: I'm not sure how the question is too broad as it is states exactly what I'm trying to do, I can post the code I've tried but it doesn't work. I didn't think this would be too complicated for someone with experience I'm just very new to VBA. I can edit with what I've tried if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the edit... "too broad" is often applied to questions with no code / seemingly no attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: First step: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. You `Set myCellRangeSetValue`... but then immediately try to use `myCellSetValue`.

Comment: Clearly missing something, idea is to select the cell in the worksheet I want to edit and then apply the value from the current selected cell in my list. Haven't gotten to getting that to then work looping through every sheet as I couldn't get it to work without looping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised code I ended up using:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("G1") = Worksheets("ABI-BE").Cells(I, 19)
    Next I
End Sub
```